# Match the indexes of two arrays and set the value of one array on the behalf of matched index value in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have two arrays one has a date as index and some value on it, like

```
$array['2013-12-05'] = 55;
```

other has list of dates as date are the indexes of it.

```
$dates['2013-12-01'] = 0;
$dates['some continual dates'] = 0;
.........
............
$dates['2013-12-15'] = 0;
```

now all i want just to match the index of $dates array with $array index date and set the value of $date's mathced index value, where all other non mathched $date index have the 0 or unchanged value.

that could be like

```
$dates['2013-12-01'] = 0;
 some in between dates.... 
$dates['2013-12-05'] = 55;
.........
............
$dates['2013-12-15'] = 0;
```

so please tell me how should i do this.. i am totaly confused now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
foreach($dates as $date => $value) {
    if (isset($array[$date])) {
      $array[$date] = $value;
    }
}
```

?

Comment: @Marc B..thanks alot for your solution. though it had a little mistake where you were setting the value of matched index. i've done it. and also editied your thanks. but thanks for the reply man.. its the solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach($dates as $date => $value1){
      if(strtotime($key)==strtotime($date))
      $dates[$key] = $value;
      else
      $dates[$date] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it could be like this

```
foreach($dates as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($array[$key])) {
      $array[$key] = $value;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $date => $value) {
    if (isset($dates[$date])) {
      $dates[$date] = $value;
    }
}
```